# CSS - overwriting issues when styling links with a specific class under another class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have been having trouble styling this group of links with the provided code, what is the correct way to style a link whose have a certain class to it or do i have an alternative with out setting global styles, only to this one link.?
i am using bootstrap class `dropdown-toggle"` to open up the drop down menu

```
<li class="bailbonds" >
   <a class="bailbondslinks" href="bailbonds.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Bail Bonds
   <b class="caret"></b>
   </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
a.bailbondslinks:link
{
    color: black;
}
a.bailbondslinks:visited
{
    color: black;
}
a.bailbondslinks:hover
{
    color: white;
}
a.bailbondslinks:active
{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: @Itay im sorry i updated the code exactly as in my notepad, i just spotted a double class declaration, could that be the problem?

Comment: you actually overriding your `bailbondslinks` class with a `dropdown-toggle` class name

Comment: @Mr_Green i just combined the two classes under the same declaration, and still not working. where is my typo? o_O

Comment: if you want a element with multiple classes, then you can do like this: `class = "bailbondslinks dropdown-toggle"`.

Comment: @Mr_Green i did that and it did not work, im not a complete newbie, i have builted quite a few websites. im really stuck here. im thinking boostrap is getting in the way

Comment: have a look at my answer now

Comment: the typo is shown in this [image](http://i.imgur.com/SMWsiyJ.png).

Comment: @Mr_Green thanks mr green, this occured when i was editing this code in the question, my coded did not have that typo, thanks alot! and i hope you referring to the green i like ^-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**  You can try like this:

```
a[class="dropdown-toggle"]:link
{
    color: black;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/p7HdC/2/

And please note that when element has two class attributes , it is simple ignoring the **second** in all browsers! Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/p7HdC/4/

**UPDATE 2** Thanks to [Wayne Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31109/wayne-austin) that mentioned that the only right solution is to have **one** class attribute , like this:

```
 <a class="bailbondslinks dropdown-toggle" href="bailbonds.php" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

Comment: I don't think that was the question

Comment: @Itay i said if i had an alternative and this answer works. bootstrap kiddies, here is our solution

Comment: @WeTheBrains There are plenty of alternatives. This solution is really coupled with the DOM.

Comment: You can't use a hyphen in CSS classes!? That's absolute rubbish, the OP is declaring two class names, the first is being overridden by the second - that is why the styles aren't applying.

Comment: @WayneAustin holy socks , this is not my day today. but you'll be discouraged when i'll say you that the first is overriding the second , have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/p7HdC/4/

Comment: @Cherniv I'm not discouraged... notice with your jsfiddle, if you change the order of your class attribute, the related style will work, one always overrides the other, it is down to the browser as to whether it acknowledges the first declaration or the second. Either way, the fix is to have one class attribute, therefore this answer is not correct.

Comment: @WayneAustin i've checked in FF , GCh , IE10 - all of them are ignoring the second. but you're right that only one solution is right - must have one and only class attribute..

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle -> you had one < more than necessary.

Is this OK?

http://jsfiddle.net/DcdeX/

```
a.bailbondslinks:link
{
    color: black;
}
a.bailbondslinks:visited
{
    color: black;
}
a.bailbondslinks:hover
{
    color: white;
}
a.bailbondslinks:active
{
    color: black;
}

<ul>
<li class="bailbonds" >
   <a class="bailbondslinks" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Bail Bonds
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, you want to style links by class. See http://jsfiddle.net/QLzV4/1/

Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="bailbonds"> 
        <a class="bailbondslinks" href="bailbonds.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Bail Bonds
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="bailbonds"> 
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Something else
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
a.bailbondslinks {
    color:black;
}
```

Followed by the pseudo-classes (e.g `:hover`)

```
a.bailbondslinks:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TYPO :**

```
<<a class="bailbondslinks" href="bailbonds.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

> 1.) **Excess <<**
>
> 2.) **class="dropdown-toggle"** may override the style you specify to your **class="bailbondslinks"**

Comment: This is the correct answer, note: if you want to apply more than one class to an element use the same attribute and separate each class name by with a space class="dropdown-toggle bailbondslink"

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
.bailbonds a:link{
    color: black;
}
.bailbonds a:visited{
    color:black;
}
```

---

and so on..